# Launch node REPL in emacs

Tags: node.js, emacs

I am new to using emacs and am trying to launch a node REPL in inferior mode to interactively run JS alongside my code. When I try running the command `C-c!`, I receive an error in the buffer saying that `C-c!` is undefined. I wasn't able to find an answer online (which is probably a function of me not using the proper search terms) and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-c !` is specific to the Python REPL. For node.js you need to type `M-x nodejs-repl`.

This requires the package nodejs-repl, found in Marmalade and MELPA; to install it, make sure you have one of those repositories set up, e.g. (from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA):

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

Then type `M-x package-install RET nodejs-repl RET`.

Comment: Presumably using some third-party library/package?

Comment: phils: Added. I was assuming the OP already had it installed.

Comment: Yes, I had debated whether to add the comment to the question or to the answer. I went with this because you'd specified a command to call. This isn't in the default GNU package archive, btw, but it does appear to be available in all the common third-party archives. I'd suggest looking at either melpa-stable or marmalade.

Comment: @phils Thanks. Updated again. I was confused by the fact that my nodejs-repl package was installed in .emacs.d/elpa.